# fast way to read in png, add grid & coords, and output

Tags: r

I have a lot of png files of a floor plan (mapping) layout that I want to:

1. read into R
2. Add grid lines
3. Add coordinates per cell in grid
4. Output

There are 1000 of these files so I'm looking for a speedy method.  What would be a fast way to accomplish this task.  These don't need to be publication quality as I'm looking for certain behavior clusters within cells and want recording the coordinated for these events for each of the 100 frames (pngs).

Here is a MWE that produces 10 png files:

```
x <- y <- seq(-4*pi, 4*pi, len = 27)
r <- sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+"))

dir.create("delete_me")
wd <- getwd()
setwd("delete_me")

lapply(1:10, function(x){
    png(sprintf("file_%s.png", x))
    image(z = z <- cos(r^2)*exp(-r/x))
    dev.off()
})

setwd(wd)
```

The final output will look like this for each png (with all the coords filled in).

I assume `grid` will be the way to create the gridlines quickly but am not sure about reading the png in quickly or plotting the coordinates (assume we'll use a 10 x 10 grid on each png).

[image]

Comment: Spatial task view has a lot of packages that deal with spatial data. The cover package is `sp` and it has some capabilities to plot grids. You will need to work with a special class, though. Have you considered adding a grid through that?

Comment: @Roman I was unaware of this.  Thank you kindly.  I will explore this.  This is a new area of analysis for me so I didn't even know this would be called spatial data (makes perfect sense though).  That gives a great starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `ggplot()` and `annotation_custom()` to plot the image across the entire plot area, then manually overplot the grid lines.

(In the image, I trimmed the excess whitespace and axis from the png file in advance)

```
# pre-req libraries
require(ggplot2)  
require(grid)     # rasterGrob function 
require(png)      # to read the PNG file

width<-10
height<-10

# generate the points and labels for the grid
points<-data.frame(expand.grid(w=1:width,h=1:height))
points$labs<-paste0("(",points$w,",",points$h,")")
points$x<-points$w-0.5 # center
points$y<-points$h-0.5

# make the gridline co-ordinates
gridx<-data.frame(x=0:width,xend=0:width,y=rep(0,width+1),yend=rep(height,width+1))
gridy<-data.frame(x=rep(0,height+1),xend=rep(width,height+1),y=0:height,yend=0:height)
grids<-rbind(gridx,gridy)

# function to plot using ggplot with annotation_custom for the image
plotgrid<-function(file){
g<-ggplot(points)+theme_bw()+
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(readPNG(file),0,0,1,1,just=c("left","bottom")),0,width,0,height)+
  geom_text(aes(x=x,y=y,label=labs))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=x,xend=xend,y=y,yend=yend),data=grids) +
  coord_cartesian(c(0,width),c(0,height))
  return(g)
}

# run the function for each file in the folder
setwd("delete_me")
lapply(list.files(),function(x)plotgrid(x))
setwd(wd)
```

[image]

Comment: this gives the desired output.  ggplot2 is a great tool I love but it tends to be slower.  I will (a) test your solution (b) wait if anyone has a faster base approach (including my own exploration of the  sp package that Roman suggested).  If I see no better alternatives I'll check this one. +1

Comment: On 38 images this takes `33.40391`.  I think we could get a speed boost by running in parallel as well.  So with 8 cores on 1000 images the task could be done in ~3 minutes.  That's not too bad.